# Arguments in scientific discussion and questioning administration on decision making

Tags: philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-mind, argumentation

While we may have a no-holds barred attitude to prove a point in a scientific deliberation, we have to be little more responsible while questioning the decision making of an administration (assuming we are part of it).

In the first case, we may eventually win the argument if we convince the scientific forum; in the second case, we almost and always will lose the battle and never come back. We may be fired, humiliated, transferred from our jobs or even can be proved to be mentally unstable.

Does any Greek philosopher talk about such things as to what our conduct should be during an administrative decision making when it is not in our favour, when we are denied of something, when we are ignored despite the hard work we put in and when somebody else gets the appreciation when we deserve it as well.

Comment: You are not as bad off as poor Boethius was (I hope) but nevertheless there may be something here to console you. Don't be thrown off by the Christian angle, because he was really a universal figure. Surely the volume is free somewhere on the internet.

Comment: Here is the Wikipedia:   https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Consolation_of_Philosophy